The results of using Eigen to calculate matrix in C++ are different on Linux and Windows platforms
I use Eigen to calculate the rotation matrix and run the same C++code on both Linux and Windows platforms as follows:
void testEigen()
{
  Eigen::AngleAxisd xRot(0.0, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitX());
  Eigen::AngleAxisd yRot(-M_PI/2, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY());
  Eigen::AngleAxisd zRot( M_PI/2, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ());
  Eigen::Quaternion<double> q = xRot * yRot * zRot;
  auto _rotationMatrix = q.matrix();
  // for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  // {
  //   for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  //   {
  //     if (std::abs(_rotationMatrix(i, j)) < 1e-13)
  //     {
  //       _rotationMatrix(i, j) = 0.0;
  //     }
  //     if (std::abs((std::abs(_rotationMatrix(i, j)) - 1.0)) < 1e-13)
  //     {
  //       _rotationMatrix(i, j) = _rotationMatrix(i, j) < 0 ? -1.0 : 1.0;
  //     }
  //   }
  // }
  TRACE(4, "angle axisd  x: " <<  std::defaultfloat << xRot.angle() << " y: " << yRot.angle() << " z: " << zRot.angle());
  TRACE(4, "m_axis axisd  x: " << xRot.axis() << " y: " << yRot.axis() << " z: " << zRot.axis());
  TRACE(4, "Rotate matrix debug init _rotationMatrix\n0: " << _rotationMatrix.row(0) << "\n1: " << _rotationMatrix.row(1) << "\n2: " << _rotationMatrix.row(2));
}

However, the output results are not quite consistent, as shown below:

windows:
angle axisd  x: 0 y: -1.5707963267948965579989817342721 z: 1.5707963267948965579989817342721
m_axis axisd  x: 1, 0, 0  y: 0, 1, 0  z: 0, 0, 1
Rotate matrix debug init _rotationMatrix
0: -4.4408920985006261616945266723633e-16        0     -1.0000000000000004440892098500626
1:  1.0000000000000004440892098500626  -4.4408920985006261616945266723633e-16           0
2:  0     -1.0000000000000004440892098500626   -4.4408920985006261616945266723633e-16
linux:
angle axisd  x: 0 y: -1.5707963267948965579989817342721 z: 1.5707963267948965579989817342721
m_axis axisd  x: 1, 0, 0  y: 0, 1, 0 z: 0, 0, 1
Rotate matrix debug init _rotationMatrix
0:                             0        -2.2204460492503130808472633361816e-16                                    -1
1:                             1         2.2204460492503130808472633361816e-16                                     0
2: 2.220446049250313080847263336181e-16           -1      2.2204460492503130808472633361816e-16


Using MSVC 2019 AMD 64 on Windows platform.

Using Gcc debian 12.2.0 used on Linux platform.

Eigen library version: Eigen 3.3.7


I want to make the running results of the two platforms consistent, thansk!

What compile flags do you use for both?

Also note that the values are essentially the same. If you want results to be the same down to the last bit, you will have a bad time. Especially since transcendental math functions like sin and cos required to build those matrices are allowed to have imperfect precision. See also the always relevant Is floating point math broken? question

Thanks，I did not use any optimized compilation options，I am also aware of floating-point errors, but I am a bit puzzled as to why it is twice as good as just right. Is this a coincidence? @Homer512

Are the results for sin(M_PI/2) and cos(M_PI/2) equal on both platforms? Have you compared the entries in the quaternion? Multiplying the rotations requires automatic conversion to quaternions. Are Quaternion<double>(xRot) etc. identical?

Thank you for providing me with an idea. After testing, everything you said is the same. I will try some other calculations.

After testing, I found that this seems to have nothing to do with the operating system. I used msvc and mingw to compile and run the test code separately on Windows, but they are inconsistent. Moreover, the program compiled by mingw has the same running results as the program compiled by gcc on Linux,@Homer512

To be absolutely certain that the sin and cos values are equal to the last bit, you can print them as integers with std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(cos(M_PI/2)) etc.

I have tried multiple times to calculate and most of the values are equal, but when executing std:: Bit_cast<std:: uint64_t>(sin (0.78539816339744828)), the program compiled by msvc outputs 460454427121702189, while the program compiled by mingw outputs 460454427121702188. Additionally, I noticed that the mingw program uses FPU during runtime, while the FPU register of the msvc program remains unchanged.@ Homer512

0.78539816339744828 is a number generated during a process of calculating quaternions previously

As suspected, the libm that comes with MSVC simply has a slightly different precision compared to the GNU version. GNU lists its errors here. At the very bottom you see a maximum error of 1 ULP for sin and cos for x86-64. MSVC makes no guarantees but I guess it's 2 rather than 0 (which would be impressive).

It's easy to miss the last few bits of precision when looking at floating point numbers in their decimal representation. Generating that representation is itself a complex operation so I'm not entirely surprised that 1 or 2 ULP errors are simply rounded off. However, when you say that mingw uses the FPU registers, does that mean you generate 32 bit code without SSE2?

Different compilers produce different computer commands that is a reason for different results. By the way, did you use the same com computer for calculations? Also, some "standard" library functions do have different implementations. Also, and it is well known that even the same compiler with different optimization levels produces slightly (or may be not) calculation results. Just, because of the rounding errors are different for different commands sequence. So, different results are not obligatory a mistake.

I am using a different computer, but the eigen is the same. I directly included the eigen source code into the project I didn't use the optimization compilation option setting (- o0) during compilation.

It is a good idea to include eigen source code into the project. I would also recommend to use the same compiler in both windows and linux. For example, gcc or icl/icx.

I know there are errors in floating-point calculations, but what confuses me is that the error here happens to be double the relationship I have another question, is it normal for the signs to be inconsistent? @Michael Ermakov

Floating point calculations could be affected not only by optimization but also different model of float calculations.

Thank you, I will try to use the same compiler to calculate the results.

I tried using mingw (gcc) and msvc to compile and run test samples on Windows today, and I found that the phenomenon is the same as before. It seems that it is not a problem at the operating system level but only related to the compiler?@Michael Ermakov

I am sure that it is not a problem of OS, but a problem of compiler and corresponding libraries.

yeah, so my current problem has become how to make eigen perform consistently on gcc and msvc!，I will try to see the difference step by step, thanks! @Michael Ermakov

I suppose the problems are mainly linked math functions: sin, cos, etc... Print function is also could be affected. Good luck.

yeah，I have found that the most basic sin and cos functions yield inconsistent results on msvc and mingw, which can cause error accumulation in my project. Is there any way to eliminate this impact?@Michael Ermakov

My suggestion is to understand which compiler produces a result consistent with the correct mathematics.
